# Dynamically ES2015 import() external module (example from Chrome 75 DevTools)

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, javascript-import

Is there a way to use dynamic imports to load into the browser Javascript libraries made available over CDN, like jQuery e.g.:

```
> import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js')
   .then(console.log)
   .catch(console.error)
```

Rather than making jQuery available, the above produces the rather obscure:

[image: Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)}]

It feels like this absurdly simple example, essentially following the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Import), should do something other than this, and in particular the script should be downloaded, parsed, and made available as the fulfillment of the promise.

The Network panel of `DevTools` indicates that the file itself was correctly downloaded, with a content-type of `content-type: application/javascript`, however there is no indication that the content was interpreted, and if it's made available it's not obvious how to access it.

Comment: The file has been interpreted. E.G.: `import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js').then( _ => console.log( $.fn.jquery ) );`

Comment: @Paulpro Are you saying that the jQuery CDN (and UMD in general) manifests as globals when importing via `import` keyword? (i.e. the observed behaviour is correct?)

Comment: I don't think UMD does anything when imported. ES6 modules need to export something for an import to be useful. jQuery isn't a module so, although it is interpreted as one, it has no exports and there is nothing useful to access from the imported module. It does assign to `window.$` while it is being interpreted, so it becomes accessible that way

Comment: "*the script should be and made available as the fulfillment of the promise*" - not sure what you mean by "the script" here. The promise is fulfilled with the namespace object of the module, containing everything that was exported. Since your jQuery script doesn't have any `export` statements, it's empty (besides the symbol).

Comment: @Bergi That makes sense. The `script` I was expecting was similar to the result of `import * as jQuery from 'jquery'` (which yields the same result unless transpiled, I suppose).

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Yes, I think transpilers (and bundlers) can work with jQuery's UniversalModuleDefinition format and provide the export as if it was a namespace object. I'm not aware of a pure-ES6-module jQuery distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import()` returns a `Promise` with all the considerations that a `Promise` entails. In this case, jQuery will be available globally, due to how jQuery initializes itself, but not until the `Promise` resolves. Keep in mind that, while the `Promise` is waiting to resolve, code elsewhere is free to run but jQuery may not be available just yet.

For example:

```js
import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js')
  .then(() => {
    jQuery('<div>Hello, World!</div>').appendTo('body');
  });
```

Or:

```js
(async () => {
  await import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js');
  jQuery('<div>Hello, World!</div>').appendTo('body');
})();
```

But this is problematic:

```html
<script>
  (async () => {
    await import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js');
    jQuery('<div>Hello, World!</div>').appendTo('body');
  })();
</script>

<script>
  // jQuery usually won't be available here, so we get an exception
  jQuery('<div>First?</div>').appendTo('body');
</script>
```

And this can be a problem, too:

```js
import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.js')
  .then(() => {
    jQuery('<div>Hello, World!</div>').appendTo('body');
  });
// No jQuery here, import hasn't resolved
jQuery('<div>First?</div>').appendTo('body');
```